# VS2013 Publish Profile Targets

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, visual-studio-2013, publish-profiles

Using diagnostic logging, I can see that when I run my publish profile, I get the message "Done building target "GatherAllFilesToPublish"" and then I get "Done building project" and then it actually does the copying of files from the PackageTmp directory to the publishUrl. Finally I get the message "Site was published successfully".

My question is, how can I run a command at the very end? I want to run a command on the publishUrl directory after the files have all been copied over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The event I was looking for is MSDeployPublish.